# Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized

Tags: python, pyside2, qtwebengine

When I run my Qt application I get the message

> Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set
>   Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute before
>   constructing QGuiApplication.

The app runs fine regardless of the fact that this is getting dumped to the terminal. I cant seem to find the root cause or really understand what this message is trying to tell me. What is this message saying and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like it's an old bug. Are you using the latest version of PyQt5 and PyQtWebengine? check this thread: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51379

Comment: Still an issue in Qt 6.2.3 (without Python). Accepted solution doesn't explain why this is necessary or what it does.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be fixed by setting AA_ShareOpenGLContexts before Spawning the QApplication.

See below an example when using PySide2

```
  from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
      qt_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

NB: As mentioned as reply in the question: When using PyQt5, checkout https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51379 instead
          ...

Comment: Even after adding this line, the issue persists.

Comment: The message comes up right after QWebEngineView is imported and before the app is even created. So this line would come after the problem has already occurred.

Comment: thanks -> normally Qt automatically creates in '__main__' -> 
app = QApplication([])  ->  so when I change as you suggested, the bug disappeared. the main reason we chose PySide2

Comment: Problem occurred for me using pyside6, just had to adjust the import line  to`from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QCoreApplication, Qt` and omit the `QtCore` namespace from the function calls

Answer (score 0):

Using PySide6 instead of PySide2 solved my problem with python 3.9 and QT 5.15 if it can help